# Тестирование приложений

Tags: linux, тестирование

Каким образом можно правильно протестировать программу в Linux? К примеру, узнать максимальное потребление памяти, количество использованного процессорного времени?

То есть, не так, чтоб открыть `htop` и посмотреть, а по аналогии с `time [application]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# valgrind --trace-children=yes time echo anus
==5286== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5286== Command: time echo anus
==5286==
==5289== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5289== Command: /bin/echo anus
==5289==
anus
==5289==
==5289== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5289==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5289==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 30 frees, 1,985 bytes allocated
==5289==
==5289== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5289==
==5289== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5289== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
0.43user 0.02system 0:00.46elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 107024maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+8687minor)pagefaults 0swaps
==5286==
==5286== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5286==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5286==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5286==
==5286== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5286==
==5286== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5286== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
```

Comment: Более-менее подходит, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В копилку:

- **perf**
  Профилировщик для GNU/Linux с подсчетом производительности.
  https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page
- **gdb**
  Дебагер от GNU, позволяющий "подсмотреть", что происходит внутри программы во вреия ее исполнения.
  https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/
- **flame graph**
  Графический профилировщик.
  http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html
- **strace**
  Используется для диагностики и дебага программ под GNU/Linux
  https://strace.io/

Comment: Спасибо, хороший список :)